# XML Node by Node into C# Array

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to get file locations out of an XML file rather than hard coding locations that could ultimately change.

I don't know how many files there will be which is causing me issue.

How can I get this function to iterate through all nodes and copy them to a new index within the array?

**update**

Is there a way to do this using arrays if you don't know the size, perhaps an ArrayList for example or chuck it into a list and convert to an array after? Whichever method would be best.

Below is the code I've written so far:

```
public static void LoadMyXML()
{
    string xmlfp = _AppPath + @"\Config";
    try
    {
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load(xmlfp);
        XmlNode xmlLst = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("parent1/child1");
        string[] xmlNodeArray;

        foreach (XmlNode node in xmlLst.ChildNodes)
        {
            //read through and add any child nodes to the array
            xmlNodeArray[] = node.InnerText;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        WriteErrorToLog("XML Loading error " + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `List`, if you don't know the size:

```
List<string> xmlNodes = new List<string>();

foreach (XmlNode node in xmlLst.ChildNodes)
{
    xmlNodes.Add(node.InnerText);
}
```

Apart from that I would suggest you use new [`Linq to XML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) API for this.

Comment: Thanks, was considering list but not really used arrays so wanted to venture out of my comfort zone - is there no way to do this using arrays if you don't know the size? ArrayList for example or chuck it into a list and convert to an array after?